# Continuity of minimum function on topological spaces

Tags: general-topology, functions, convergence-divergence, continuity

The question I have is the following:

Suppose $X,Y$ are compact Hausdorff topological spaces and $f: X \times Y \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous. Define $g: X \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by $g(x) = \min_{y \in Y} f(x,y)$.  Show that $g$ is continuous on $X$ using basic definitions of continuity.  I hypothesized using the closed graph theorem ($g$ is a closed map) but the prompt wants me to use basic characterizations of continuity.

My basic approach was to let $(x_n)_{n=1}^{\infty} \subset X$ converge to $x \in X$.  Then for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, there exists a $y_n \in Y$ corresponding to $\text{argmin}_{y \in Y} f(x_n,y)$.  Consider the sequence $(x_n,y_n) \subset X \times Y$.  Since $Y$ is compact, we can drop to a subsequence $(x_{n_k},y_{n_k})_{k=1}^{\infty}$ such that $(x_{n_k},y_{n_k}) \longrightarrow (x,y)$.

This is where I get stuck.  I don't even know if $g(x_{n_k})=f(x_{n_k},y_{n_y}) \longrightarrow f(x,y) = g(x)$ since $y$ need not be a minimizing value of $f$.

Even if it was, I will have only shown that the image of a specific subsequence under $g$ converges.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you may not be ably to use sequential continuity here. what if $X$ or $Y$ are not metric spaces? how do you guarantee that sequential continuity and continuity are equivalent?

Comment: Very good point.  I'm actually not even sure that this is even a true statement.

Comment: same.  i have been trying to cook up counter examples too

Comment: Assuming $T_X=\{X,\emptyset,\{1\}\}$. $g^{-1}(-1/2,1/2)=\{0\}$ which is not open in $X$ is what i think you were trying to say. But by the same reasoning, $f^{-1}(-1/2,1/2)=\{(0,0)\}$ which is also not an open subset of $X\times Y$ so $f$ isn’t continuous.

Comment: Do you have access to the tube lemma?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131196/discussion-between-isochron-and-c-squared).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can quickly see this to be true using some category theory as follows:

Since everything in sight is locally compact and hausdorff, we know (by the [exponential adjunction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_object)) that maps $f : X \times Y \to \mathbb{R}$ are the same thing as maps $\tilde{f} : X \to \mathbb{R}^Y$, where $\mathbb{R}^Y$ is given the [compact-open topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact-open_topology). Since $Y$ is compact and $\mathbb{R}$ is metric, this agrees with the $\sup$-norm topology. But it's clear that $\min : \mathbb{R}^Y \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous with respect to the $\sup$-norm topology on $\mathbb{R}^Y$, and we're done.

We can unravel this category theoretic language to get a proof using only "basic" facts as follows:

Say $f : X \times Y \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous.

1. Show the map $x \mapsto f(x,-) : X \to C(Y)$ is continuous, where $C(Y)$ is the space of continuous functions on $Y$ with the $\sup$-norm.
2. Show the map $g \mapsto \min_y g(y) : C(Y) \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous.
3. Then conclude $x \mapsto f(x,-) \mapsto \min_y f(x,y)$ is continuous, as a composite of continuous functions.

If you're struggling to show $1$, you might want to look into "joint continuity" being stronger than "separate continuity". If you're struggling to show $2$, you might consider the identity

$$\min_y g(y) = - \left ( \big \lVert \lVert g \rVert_\infty - g \big \rVert_\infty - \lVert g \rVert_\infty \right )$$

(notice $\lVert g \rVert_\infty - g \geq 0$, and its maximum value is $\lVert g \rVert_\infty$ more than the minimum value of $g$).

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Thanks for in depth reply! This is for an analysis course, so most of this flew over my head, but still very interesting.  Do you know if this result fails when X,Y are only assumed compact (and not Hausdorff)?  I've been trying to come up with some counter examples.